# Django datepicker issue, $ is not recognised

Tags: javascript, django, datepicker

Hi fully aware that this looks like a duplicate, but it's not, the fixes for the other questions did not solve this issue. I'm trying to add a datepicker to my django forms, but I've never used jquery before, but now it seems I have to, but can't get it working. I'm trying to follow this guide https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html#fengyuan-chens-datepicker and trying to use the fengyuanchen_datepicker. I can't get it working at all and I think it is because of the cdn links at the top of the page. 
Here is the header:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Project Portal+ :: sidev</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'project_portal/images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'project_portal/css/project_portal.css' %}">    
  <link type="application/javascript"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/i18n/datepicker.en-GB.min.js">
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

and here is the html I am trying to get it working in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "project_portal/base.html" %}

{% block detail %}
<div class="project_setup">
  <h1>Project Setup</h1>
  <form class="update" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
    <a href="{% url 'project-list' %}">Cancel</a>    
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#id_date").datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      });
  });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm assuming the "$" is a jquery thing, which i personally would rather not use as it's really bloated just to do this one thing, but I can't find another way to do it currently as bootstrap is off limits as it messes with my current css. What can I do to get this to work please.

Comment: Why are you loading `datepicker.en-GB.min.js` with a `<link>` tag? Use `<script src="...`

Comment: No idea, this is what i have been scouring the internet for, but i'm obviously not asking the right question, I'm sure that what I have is right except the links in the header, I've avoided jquery like the plague, but I can't find a vaniller javascript datepicker to use.

Comment: You need a script reference to the datepicker library too.

Comment: @iFunction but I think that could be the problem. Try load it in a script tag.

Comment: Remove `<link type="application/javascript"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/i18n/datepicker.en-GB.min.js">` and add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/i18n/datepicker.en-GB.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @BrettGregson Ok, i've just tried that, but still getting "$ is not defined" error

Comment: Check you network tab, is jQuery actually loading? And are you sure it's not being loaded twice

Comment: @BrettGregson Got that bit working, thank you, the datepicker doesn't work, but that's fine I obviously haven't implimented it correctly, but no more errors, thans for your help

Comment: @xyres yup, gotta downvote the dyslexics. Not everyone is perfect, sorry.

Comment: @iFunction glad you got it working. If the picker isn't working, double check you're selecting the correct element: `$("#id_date")` in your question so an input with id `id_date` must exist

Comment: @BrettGregson Got ya, yes, this is what I mean when I say I haven't done any javascript. What you say makes perfect sense.